# WordPress REST API and Backbone JS

Tags: filters, javascript, rest-api, backbone

I am trying to learn WordPress Rest API using Backbone.js the official library, there aren't many tutorials, and that's why I am asking this question right here.

First question is why when I add WP-API as a dependency in my JS script, does Jquery get enqueued also?

The second question is how would you get the paginated posts in a collection, using the post.more() doesn't seem to work, same for post.getFeaturedMedia().done()

If anyone can share a tutorial code, I would appreciate it.

Comment: As to helping with your code, we can't do that unless you post your code.  As for help with backbone, did you look at the wordpress developers site?  Specifically this page:  https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/ or the learning site?  https://learn.wordpress.org/tutorial/interacting-with-the-wordpress-rest-api/

Comment: you shouldn't consider backbone.js to be the "official" library, it hasn't been used in core for new things in years. All new development for the last few years has been done using React and modern JS packages. Before that was the case backbone.js was still rarely used outside of the customizer and media library as it was difficult to learn and poorly documented. You're very much playing WordPress in ultra hard mode if you want to use backbone

Comment: @rudtek that's that video that got me introduced to WP rest API and backbone.js btw, I am following the documentation but I can't seem to be able to use the pagination in postsCollection.more() it's not working https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/#collection-examples

Comment: @TomJNowell I did not know that, I got introduced to backbone js and rest API on recent tutorial on WordPress, trying to use it to replace Ajax filtering for posts :)

Comment: the REST API yay! Backbone not so much. There's a WP API utility library that talks to the REST API, but it's far easier and more reliable to use standard JS ecosystem packages to talk directly to the REST API. Even a lot of WP stuff didn't use backbone, it's just what was used for those 2 features, e.g. menu and widget management don't use backbone or React

Comment: ps: another user asked a very similar question not long ago, perhaps they saw the same tutorial, I hope someone notable isn't recommending the use of backbone, do you have any leads?

Comment: @TomJNowell I am following Jonathan Bossenger tutorials on WordPress official channel :)

Comment:  I was talking to him not long ago in person, do you have a link?

Comment: @TomJNowell https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeNm_gxGuY8 here you go :)

Comment: I found it on the Learn WP and DM'd him, it's intended to be part of a series that also uses React, backbone is just an example used in a step by step process

Comment: @TomJNowell Yea he told me also :D btw how would u use Rest API if you were creating a standard theme without Blocks? Vanilla js or?

Comment: I don't see how the answer would be different wether it was or was not a block theme, and that maybe you're overthinking the REST API. You make a HTTP request to a URL and it returns information in JSON, people have been making those kinds of requests for decades even before WordPress existed. e.g. `fetch(...)` or `jQuery.get(...)`, you don't need a framework and a special library to talk to the REST API, and talking to the REST API doesn't need special encantations, it's just a page with JSON at a URL